# how to summary values in specific range?

Tags: php, for-loop

```
        $srv2 = 0;
        foreach ($result as $value) {

            for($i = 0; $i >= 11 && $i <= 20; $i++){
                $srv2 += $value['words_count'];
            }
            if ($i > 20)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Can sameone tell me what is wrong ? I want to summarry all values in range 11-20 included 11.

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i >= 11 && $i <= 20; $i++){` replace with `for($i = 11; $i <= 20; $i++){` first one wont loop, because you will have your $i=0 and loop will end because it is less than11.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Change your for loop to

```
srv2 = 0;
foreach ($result as $value) {

    for($i = 11; $i <= 20; $i++){
        $srv2 += $value['words_count'];
    }
    if ($i > 20)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, and now what if i need next range from foreach loop, like: 

` $srv3 = 0;
foreach ($result as $value) {

    for($i = 21; $i <= 30; $i++){
        $srv3 += $value['words_count_out_a'];
    }
    if ($i > 30)
    {
        break;
    }
}`

and i got the samne result like srv2

Comment: How to use for loop to set range of foreach loop ??

I got this: but not working still summary only first results 1-10, I got in this fetch 100 results, need to summary for examplek position from 20 to 30, got something like this:

`/21-30
    $srv3 = 0;
foreach ($result as $value) {

    for($i = 21; $i <= 30; $i++){
        $srv3 += $value['words_count_out_a'];
    }
    if ($i > 30)
    {
        break;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $srv3 = 0;
foreach ($result as $value) {

    for($i = 21; $i <= 30; $i++){
        $srv3 += $value['words_count'];
    }
    if ($i > 30)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

and result is the same like in 2, but its inpossible,

Comment: I think i next for loop, 2,3,4,5,6,7... need to use && or || in for loop

Comment: give nothing, when use &&